# Running the `code` command creates two new windows on wsl + tmux

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tmux

I am new to Tmux , and I am trying to configure it with my WSL instance.

This is the initial setup so far:
[image]

but when I want to open a directory into vscode, without tmux I would run `code .` and vscode would open the current directory as the folder. Now with Tmux what happens is:
VSCode launches the current dir as the folder but also two new windows pop up in tmux, one that has the path for vscode as the cwd and one that is has the directory that I opened vscode from as the cwd.

All windows pictured bellow:

Initial window invoking vscode:
[image]

New window with vscode's path as cwd:
[image]

New window with the same cwd as the initial invoker of `code .`:
[image]

And the vscode app with the cwd of `bin`:
[image]

I have observed that these two new windows only appear if vscode isn't currently running.

I don't know if this is a tmux, wsl, zsh, p10k, oh-my-zsh, vscode or anyother program's issue.

Comment: Which program/script hides  behind `code` in your environment, i.e. what do you see when you do on the command line a `type code`?

Comment: this is the output of `type code`

code is /home/ledrake/.vscode-server/bin/863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6/bin/remote-cli/code

Comment: I'm surprised that vscode really hides its executable under such a weird path. So you installed vscode on purpose locally in your home? Why? Is there any other executable named `code` under your home? (Do a `find ~ -type f -executable -name code`).

Comment: running the command gives the following :

`/home/ledrake/.vscode-server/bin/863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6/bin/remote-cli/code`

Comment: While this is not **necessarily** wrong, it is unusual, because people typically install vscode globally, and it ends up then as i.e. /usr/bin/code. Would it be an option for you to do such a typical install, or did you have specific reasons for doing that local install? In any case, the problem seems to be related to the way you have installed vscode, and your question is therefore not suitable for stackoverflow. I suggest that you ask this question at [su], but also describe exactly, how you have installed vscode.

Comment: I have been using vscode, way before the installation of WSL on my machine, if i understand correctly you suggest i uninstall vscode from Windows and install it on wsl ??

Comment: Did you try running a Windows version of vscode from WSL???? I can't tell you what you have to pay attention to if you want to do this. This too is a question to ask on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem and solution was:

In my .zshrc file i had a stanza to open tmux on terminal creation,

`if [ "$TMUX" = "" ]; then exec tmuxn; fi`

removing this was the solution.

Comment: An `exec` in your zsh file never makes sense, as it replaces zsh with the executed program. This has the effect that you don't run zsh anymore .....